# Make image in picture element fit its container

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```css
#container {
  background: steelblue;
  width: 333px;
  height: 333px;
}

picture img {
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <picture>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/300" alt="kitten">
  </picture>
</div>
```

How can I get the picture to fill the container box?

[Here's a codepen](https://codepen.io/Ciwan/pen/QaNvGa).

Comment: mike already answered it just want to add, "object-fit" is not supported for IE and not perfectly supported for edge, just incase this is important for your usage ;) https://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit

Comment: What's the point of using `<picture>` without the `<source>` elements?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You have to use `display:flex` in 'picture' element (in conjunction with `object-fit` property for the 'img')

This will work, for any size of the container.

like so:

```css
#container {
  background: steelblue;
  width: 333px;
  height: 500px;
  
}
picture {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
 
}
picture img {
 object-fit: cover; 
    height: auto;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <picture>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/300" alt="kitten">    
  </picture>
</div>
```

Comment: This works for me, but wondering why it works?

Comment: All I needed was img width 100%. Setting those properties on the picture tag did nothing for me.

Comment: Its worth pointing out something that tripped me up. I had a <picture> tag with a bunch of <source> tags inside as well as a <img> fallback. Even if your picture is using one of the <source> tags for its image source it will still honour the styles you apply to the <img> tag. I was applying object-fit to the <picture> which was why it didnt work for me initially. I hope this helps someone else under the same misapprehension.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `width: 100%;` to your img. It will fit to the container if both are squares.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to add `width` and `height` to the `img`:

```
img {
  width : 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Also use the `object-fit` **CSS property** to specify how the element should be resized to fit its container. To preserve the aspect-ratio :

```
object-fit: contain;
```

As per [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) :

> **contain**
>
> The replaced content is scaled to maintain its aspect ratio
> while fitting within the element’s content box.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a long time to figure out because I was trying to add the style of `width: 100%` to the picture tag, instead of adding it to the 'img' tag directly.

Answer (score -1):

You have to stretch BOTH picture and img elements:

```
#container {
  background: steelblue;
  width: 333px;
  height: 333px;
}

picture, img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```