# How can I make a image keep it's proportion independent of the browser size inside a div?

Tags: css, reactjs, image, jsx

So what I want is to change the browser size and keep the img of background as 100% width and height and inside of the div, here is the image:

- https://github.com/MestreALMO/NextLevelWeek2020Day06Plus/blob/master/_ReadmeImgs/searchingForThisEffect/Screenshot_3.png?raw=true

Changing its proportion when needed be so it does not get stretched like so:

- Image when page is compressed: https://github.com/MestreALMO/NextLevelWeek2020Day06Plus/blob/master/_ReadmeImgs/searchingForThisEffect/Screenshot_3.2.png?raw=true
- Image when page is streched:
  https://github.com/MestreALMO/NextLevelWeek2020Day06Plus/blob/master/_ReadmeImgs/searchingForThisEffect/Screenshot_3.3.png?raw=true

Here is a part of my code:

```
var backgroundLoginContainer01 = {
    backgroundImage: `url(${Background})`
}
```

Then i call it like this:

```
<div style={backgroundLoginContainer01} />
```

Comment: use backgroundSize: cover

Comment: I didn't geit it, how can i insert it in snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another (and better) solution would be to put your image inside `<picture>` tags, and then style the image with the propriety "object-fit: cover". You will find this solution detailed [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47888165/make-image-in-picture-element-fit-its-container).

EDIT:

Given the examples that you provided in the edit, I think that what you are looking for is `background-size: 100% 100%;`. Look the following demo.

```css
div {
    background-image:url('https://via.placeholder.com/150');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    height: 30vh; 
    width: 30vw; 
}
```

```html
<body>
<div>

</div>
</body
```

Comment: for what you said i think the snippet code i just did should work, but it doesn't

Comment: Hi @MestreALMO, look at my edit. Let me know if that help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var backgroundLoginContainer01 = {
    backgroundImage: `url(${Background})`,
    backgroundSize: 'cover',
}
```

if you want to do with css

```
.bg {
  background-image: url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MestreALMO/NextLevelWeek2020Day06Plus/700f9f9524fee4dff926fe26cfa33ef92b9e0457/web/src/assets/images/success-background.svg");
  background-size: cover,
}
```

[check this example](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_background-size3)

Comment: that is nice, but it really isn't what i was looking for, the img is getting cut to fit the div i wanted it to compress it self so 100% of image would be displayed at all times. i'll edit the original message and insert there some images of the effect i'm looking for

Comment: check this https://jsbin.com/welcome/1/edit?html,css,output
change the content width and height